# bash - split but only use certain numbers

Tags: bash, split

let's say I want to split a large file into files that have - for example - 50 lines in them

```
split <file> -d -l 50 prefix
```

How do I make this ignore the first `n` and the last `m` lines in the `<file>`, though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `head` and `tail`:

```
tail -n +N [file] | head -n -M | split -d -l 50
```

Ex (`lines` is a textfile with 10 lines, each with a consecutive number):

```
[bart@localhost playground]$ tail -n +3 lines | head -n -2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

Comment: This doesn't allow to pass a prefix to the split command, does it?

Comment: No, strangely enough it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

If `n` and `m` have the start and the end line number to print, you can do this

with `sed`

```
sed -n $n,${m}p file
```

`-n` avoid printing by default all lines. `p` is printing only the line that matches the range indicated by `$n,${m}`

---

With `awk`

```
awk "NR>$n && NR<$m" file
```

where `NR` represent the number of line

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk` over the file that is splitted, by provide a range of lines you need.

```
awk -v lineStart=2 -v lineEnd=8 'NR>=lineStart && NR<=lineEnd' splitted-file
```

E.g.

```
$ cat line
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

The `awk` with range from 3-8 by providing

```
$ awk -v lineStart=3 -v lineEnd=8 'NR>=lineStart && NR<=lineEnd' file
3
4
5
6
7
8
```